# AAD B2C MSAL for python Token Validation without the public key in JWKS_URI

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-msal, aad-b2c

Hello Everyone I could REALLY use some help on this.

When trying to validate my token using this code from MSAL library https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python

cache = _load_cache()  # This web app maintains one cache per session

```
cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)

accounts = cca.get_accounts()

if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user

    result = cca.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])

    _save_cache(cache)

    return result
```

I grab the id_token from the returned dictionary which is base64 encoded

And it returns a header of:

{

"typ": "JWT",

"alg": "RS256",

"kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk"

}

Payload of:

{

"exp": 1664743047,

"nbf": 1664739447,

"ver": "1.0",

"iss": "https://******.b2clogin.com/*******/v2.0/",

"sub": "*******",

"aud": "22b52070-255a-4de8-b9ac-f6f37498e6bb",

"nonce": "a0da49a5916f3cf9a4fc7432782dba443f7a0e5dafce19f8c919b3e6a1ef67f6",

"iat": 1664739447,

"auth_time": 1664699840,

"oid": "*******",

"given_name": "Gabriel",

"tfp": "B2C_1_susi"

}

It is my understanding that there should be a key of "x5t" containing the public key I can use to validate the signature.

When I run the code below to verify my signature it comes back as invalid..which confuses me because I know the token came from AAD.

from azure_ad_verify_token import verify_jwt

azure_ad_app_id = '*******'

azure_ad_issuer = 'https://exampletenant.b2clogin.com/0867afa-24e7-40e9-9d27-74bb598zzzzc/v2.0/'

azure_ad_jwks_uri = 'https://exampletenant.b2clogin.com/exampletenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_app_sign_in/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid=*********'

payload = verify_jwt(

```
token='<AZURE_JWT_TO_VERIFY_HERE>',

valid_audiences=[azure_ad_app_id],

issuer=azure_ad_issuer,

jwks_uri=azure_ad_jwks_uri,

verify=True,
```

)

I am at a complete loss and have not been able to find any answers. Please help when you can thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> trying to validate my token using this code from MSAL library https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python

> I grab the `id_token` from the returned dictionary which is base64 encoded

> So not a complete answer but you can check out this repo https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose

You should not need to use Python-Jose.

The recent versions of MSAL Python library are able to also return a `id_token_claims` from the returned dictionary. Those claims are payload that has already been validated for you, so you do not need to.

Answer (score 0):

So not a complete answer but you can check out this repo https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose
Import this module "pip install python-jose[cryptography]"
and you can use the code below. Should return True if the signature is valid and the decrypted payload.

```
token = "Your base 64 id_token here"
rsa_key = {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk",
    "use": "sig",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "n": "your modulus",
    "e": "your exponent"  #for example "AQAB"
}
key = jwk.construct(rsa_key)
message, encoded_sig = token.rsplit('.', 1)
decoded_sig = base64url_decode(encoded_sig + '=' * (4 - len(encoded_sig) % 4)) # looks weird, but without added padding I got errors
res = key.verify(bytes(message, "UTF-8"), decoded_sig)
# jwt.decode(token=token, key=key.to_pem().decode(), algorithms= 'RS256') # with PEM key
allowed_aud = "22b52070-255a-4de8-b9ac-f6f37498e6bb"
payload = jwt.decode(token, rsa_key, audience=allowed_aud,algorithms='RS256') # with JWK
print(res)
print(payload)
```